# Django testing of multi-db with automatic routing

Tags: django, django-testing, django-orm

Simple problem - I'm using [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) successfully with [automatic routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) setup as documented on a legacy db (which are unmanaged).  Now I want to test it.  I've already set a testrunner to get around the [managed problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161173/django-tests-complain-of-missing-tables?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I can confirm that I am creating the databases and as expected.

My problem is that the database routing is still trying to look at the non-test database.  How can I setup my routers.py file to look at the test_ database when in test mode and the non-test database any other time.

Should be simple but I'm beating my head on the wall over this one..

FWIW:

```
class PmCatalogRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the PmCatalog application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on pmCatalog models to 'catalog'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'pmCatalog':
            return 'catalog'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on pmCatalog models to 'catalog'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'pmCatalog':
            return 'catalog'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the pmCatalog app only appears on the 'catalog' db"
        if db == 'catalog':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'pmCatalog'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'pmCatalog':
            return False
        return None
```

Much appreciate the additional eyeballs on this ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - so here's what happened.  Turns out it was completely working all along, but two separate issues caused my tests from passing.  In this case I am testing the django query methods against the legacy methods.  I wasn't passing my test because the legacy methods where not looking at the test database but rather the original database.   I fixed that problem and then I realized that the procedures where not getting created in the testrunner.

Once these two problems were corrected everything magically fell together...

HTH someone.