# Running tests with unmanaged tables in django

Tags: django, django-testing

My django app works with tables that are not managed and have the following defined in my model like so:

```
class Meta:
    managed  = False
    db_table = 'mytable'
```

When I run a simple test that imports the person, I get the following:

```
(person)bob@sh ~/person/dapi $  > python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
DatabaseError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'db_Om_no'")
```

The tests.py is pretty simple like so:

```
import person.management.commands.dorecall
from person.models import Person
from django.test import TestCase
import pdb

class EmailSendTests(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        person = Person.objects.all()[0]
        Command.send_email()
```

I did read in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/) where it says "For tests involving models with managed=False, it’s up to you to ensure the correct tables are created as part of the test setup.". So I understand that my problem is that I did not create the appropriate tables. So am I supposed to create a copy of the tables in the `test_person` db that the test framework created?

Everytime I run the tests, the `test_person` db gets destroyed (I think) and re-setup, so how am I supposed to create a copy of the tables in `test_person`. Am I thinking about this right?

**Update:**

I saw [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161173/django-tests-complain-of-missing-tables) and added the `ManagedModelTestRunner()` in `utils.py`. Though `ManagedModelTestRunner()` does get run (confirmed through inserting `pbd.set_trace()`), I still get the `Duplicate column name` error. I do not get errors when I do `python manage.py syncdb` (though this may not mean much since the tables are already created - will try removing the table and rerunning syncdb to see if I can get any clues).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, where I had an unmanaged legacy database that also had a custom database name set in the models meta property.

Running tests with a managed model test runner, as you linked to, solved half my problem, but I still had the problem of Django not knowing about the custom_db name:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "custom_db" does not exist
```

The issue was that `./manage.py makemigrations` still creates definitions of all models, managed or not, and includes your custom db names in the definition, which seems to blow up tests. By installing:

```
pip install django-test-without-migrations==0.2
```

and running tests like this:

```
./manage.py test --nomigrations
```

I was able to write tests against my unmanaged model without getting any errors.

Comment: I know this post is old, but hopefully this helps someone out.

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks a lot. Working with legacy database in Django is PITA.