# Django test table is not created

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a django website using latest version of django(1.7.4 as of now). When I run my tests, they all fail because django complains one of my models doesn't exist in the test database. The error is below:

```
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
  super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
  super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
  failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
  old_config = self.setup_databases()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
  return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
  serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 385, in create_test_db
  self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 421, in serialize_db_to_string
  serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
  s.serialize(queryset, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
  for obj in queryset:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 417, in get_objects
  for obj in queryset.iterator():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
  for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
  for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
  six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 129, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
  self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
  raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_app.user_detail' doesn't exist")
```

The strange thing is that my model is defined as:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_detail'

    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
```

EVERY other model (from all apps) in my `settings.py` are created. For some reason this one app is the only one where the model doesn't exist on the test db. Is there anything else i'm doing wrong here? Why is this one table not being created?

**EDIT**

turns out I had to put `managed = False` in the `Meta`.

Comment: did you run `./manage.py syncdb` ?

Comment: Yes. ran that as well as the migrations, etc.

Comment: It's only when i'm running the tests that the model isn't created.

Comment: why add db_table = 'user_detail'?

Comment: I needed that table name. Django always has its own way of naming tables. But I needed that for compatibility with an already existing table.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161173/django-tests-complain-of-missing-tables

Comment: Works! I added `managed = False` and it works. But I honestly have no clue why. If you add that below i'll accept as an answer.

Comment: @KVISH thank you, but I think, the right way would be to close it as a duplicate..hope you agree.